# Thrift client code in Cocoa is not working

Tags: thrift

I'm using thrift as a server, I created both `server.py` and `client.py`. It works, but when I create a cocoa version of client file, it will always raise `Exception` called `No protocol version head`.

I got stuck for hours and don't know what to do. I read all the document and source code I could.

What does `No protocol version head` mean?

gist link is https://gist.github.com/GuoJing/e016efb1eb10dc5a702d

Answer (score 1):

Binary has two options which control writing and reading the message version header. This header is an 32 bit integer carrying both the protocol version (mask `0xFFFF0000`) and the message type (mask `0x0000FFFF`). The protocol version has been added later, so it may be missing.

If you set `strict = true` but the other side does not provide  the protocol version number you will see this error.

So the solution is to set `strictRead` to false, or have the other side providing the data using `strictWrite`

Comment: If I set strictRead to false, cocoa client will get stuck and wait for response.